# Capturing prompt values within a function for SVG transformations

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-svg

I have this function and i want to grab the values from the prmpts and instert them in the transformation matrix. For some reason this is not working. I am thinking that the problem is because i need to use "" before and after each var but because its already within the " " 's of the transformation matrix i cant nest them. Any ideas?

This is my code.

```
<script>
function output() {
    var transformw = prompt("Enter your new width");
    var transformh = prompt("Enter your new height");
    var newnew = 4;
    svgCanvas.changeSelectedAttribute("transform", "matrix( transformw, 0, 0, transformh, 0, 0)");
    svgCanvas.recalculateAllSelectedDimensions();
}
</script>
```

I have this function and i want to grab the values from the prmpts and instert them in the transformation matrix. For some reason this is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because this is a string:

```
"matrix( transformw, 0, 0, transformh, 0, 0)"
```

You should concatenate the string with the variables, like this:

```
svgCanvas.changeSelectedAttribute("transform", "matrix(" + transformw + ", 0, 0, " + transformh + ", 0, 0)");
```

Comment: THANK YOU! i used transformW=parseInt(transformw) below the prompt lines. Same for transformh and it still didnt work. Any ideas why? Doesnt this turn the string into an integer? Your line worked like a charm thanks.